# shell_exec how to pass arrays

Tags: arrays, parameters, shell-exec

I want to pass parameters in a file that will run background in order to send emails.

```
shell_exec("php /path/to/the/background/script.php '$arrayObjects' > /dev/null &");
```

When I var_dump the parameter $arrayObjects I get as output

```
Array
```

actually it is passed as string.

Does someone know how to pass arrays?

Comment: I'm not a PHP guy, but you'll need to add your elements as a space-separated string to the command: `"php script.php " + join(" ", $array)`, or something like that

Answer (score -1):

php shell_exec is a command line interface so it can only accept strings as arguments.

if you haven't solved it yet then maybe you can use `foreach` loop to execute mail script for each mail.

try this:

```
$emails = array ( 
          // list of emails
          );

foreach( $emails as $email ) {
    shell_exec("php /path/to/the/background/script.php '$email["email"]' > /dev/null &");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi mehul i have one doubt

Comment: @user3663 join the php chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php